How to access a control rig c++ variable in blueprint?
I have a custom control rig class and I want to expose a variable in it to the Anim Graph, I tried this:
#include "ControlRig.h"
#include "CustomControlRig.generated.h"

UCLASS(Blueprintable)
class MYPROJECT_API UCustomControlRig : public UControlRig {
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
    public:
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite)
        bool SomeVariable = false;
}

But I can't access it in the anim graph when I make a control rig node similar to how I declared this other variable in blueprints itself:

Infact I can't even access it the rig graph itself:

